# javascript delete elements from array of objects that are not present in another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays with different objects, but I need some kind of map function to map the 2 arrays to the newArray. The newArray has the same object type of arr1.

```
let arr = [{Id: 1, Name:'test'}, {Id: 2, Name:'test2'}]
let secondarr = [{value:'test'}, {value:'test3'}]
const newArray = [{Id: 1, Name: 'test'}, {Id: null, value: 'test3'}];

arr.forEach(element => {
  let exists = false;
  secondarr.forEach(i => {
    if(i.value === element.Name) {
      exists = true;
    }
  });
  if(exists) {
    secondarr = secondarr.filter(l => l.value !== element.Name);
  }
  if(!exists) {
    arr = arr.filter(l => l.Name !== element.Name);
  }
});

secondarr.forEach(element => {
  const newObj = {Id: null, Name: element.value};
  arr.push(newObj);
});
```

Comment: Did you try it ? What's the problem ? If you see no smart way, start with the dumb obvious one, that is loop over the objects you want to augment, and augment them one by one following your specification.

Comment: Why you do not have `{Id: 2, Name:'test2'}` in `newArray`?

Comment: What if there is a duplicate between `arr1` and `arr2`? What do you expect in `newArray` in this case?

Comment: Heading and description does not matched. In heading you are asking for delete.

Comment: "Dumb obvious one" are simple plain working solutions. Always start with them. You will have all the time you want later to improve them.

Comment: 'test2' does not exist in arr2 so it can't be present in newArray

Comment: @J.D could you post an attempt of code? Even pseudo-code would be a start.

Comment: @J.D Is it possible to have duplicate inside one array?

Comment: @J.D You already wrote that you're looking for some map function, so maybe start with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) and come back with some attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) to walk arr2 and use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find) to get the matching element.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZC9DoIwEIBn@xS3AYmWgBumGkcddHA0DhWqKSktKcWfEJ4dLRWC06XX@@6@u5w@aJVqXpqFVBnrulTJygDVOgIC52aXJRDN4UALlniGVcZr59Bn42k29toLGtG4Rx9U1FNo8l7aciSYAcmeW63p@0tYEBe09F9A1tCgmevHDSvcb4RvXGa@uua24BuwFQBCCLxw3z1AM81MraWjNi4k0IA1lrUQP@kBgBa1wQr16kowLNTd35@OB1wZzeWd397@YBgECIWhc5pY/58I/m/kJrrFYdx81XUf)

```
const arr1 = [{Id: 1, Name:'test'}, {Id: 2, Name:'test2'}]
const arr2 = [{value:'test'}, {value:'test3'}]

const newArray = arr2.map(x => {
    // we search for the matching element.
    const item = arr1.find(obj => obj.Name === x.value)
    // if item exists get item, else create a new one
    return item ? item : { Id: null, Name: x.value }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray))
```

output

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"test"},{"Id":null,"Name":"test3"}]
```

Comment: @J.D next time add more informations to your question though (tests, attempts, MCVE, etc.). This answer is a first step and should let you continue. You want to handle for duplicate and more. Also, take the time to check both the documentation of map and find.